# How to express this function mathematically

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

How would you express this loop in C# as a mathematical expression?

```
private string FormatBytes(long bytes)
{
    string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    int i;
    double dblSByte = bytes;
    for (i = 0; i < Suffix.Length && bytes >= 1024; i++, bytes /= 1024)
    {
        dblSByte = bytes / 1024.0;
    }

    return String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", dblSByte, Suffix[i]);
}
```

Comment: Define "mathematically".

Comment: Using maths to express the outcome of the function

Comment: Like so: https://puu.sh/xl6VX/155c777cdf.png

Comment: He means "can you calculate this without using a loop", I think.

Comment: This question has an answer, but does it belong to SO? In [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) C# code would be offtopic I guess. Hmm.. Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284157) what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if there's an expression, something you can write using simple maths which would allow someone to understand the function.

Comment: Since you have 5 cycles at maximum you can try to represent it as [combination of if/else](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15629).

Comment: Let B==1, KB==1024, MB==1024*KB, GB=1024*MB, TB==1024*GB. Then FormatBytes(x) = x. I.e. the string represented value is unchanged. It is only the representation of the number of bytes with using widely used acronyms. It is like formatting 5000m as 5km, that too does not change the represented length.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate this mathematically by first working out the nearest smaller power of 1024 to the number:

```
int power = (int) Math.Log(bytes, 1024)
```

Then you can limit that number to the number of suffixes so you don't go past the end of the array:

```
int power = Math.Min(Suffix.Length-1, (int) Math.Log(bytes, 1024));
```

Then you work out what you should divide the original number by based on that power:

```
double div = Math.Pow(1024, power);
```

Then you can format the string using the suffix for the specified power of 1024:

```
return string.Format("{0:f1}{1}", bytes / div, Suffix[power]);
```

Putting this all together (and throwing in "PB" for petabytes):

```
private string FormatBytes(long bytes)
{
    string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" };
    int power = Math.Min(Suffix.Length-1, (int) Math.Log(bytes, 1024));
    double div = Math.Pow(1024, power);

    return string.Format("{0:f1}{1}", bytes / div, Suffix[power]);
}
```

Et voila! Calculated mathematically without using a loop.

(I bet this isn't measurably faster than the loop though...)

If you wanted to you could extend the suffix array to include "exobyte" and then it would work nicely all the way to `int.MaxValue`, which is 8.0EB.